# Combining 2 ARM templates ( Action Group and Budget Alert)

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am having a bit of an issue in combining two ARM templates. I want to create an Action Group and then subsequently create an Azure budget alert. I am able to do them individually but I want to create a single Arm template to achieve the task.

**Works Fine** -Here is the code to create Action Group **(Getting the Option to select Resource Group or create one)**

```
{
        "type": "microsoft.insights/actionGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
        "name": "OG",
        "location": "Global",
        "properties": {
            "groupShortName": "OG",
            "enabled": true,
            "emailReceivers": [
                {
                    "name": "[concat('Test','OG')]",
                    "emailAddress": "someemailID@xxx.com",
                    "useCommonAlertSchema": true
                }
            ]
        }
```

**Works Fine** - Here is the code to create Budget Alert **(Getting the option to select Subscription)**

```
    "resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Consumption/budgets",
        "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
        "name": "[parameters('budgetName')]",
        "properties": {
            "timePeriod": {
                "startDate": "[parameters('startDate')]",
                "endDate": "[parameters('endDate')]"
            },
            "timeGrain": "[parameters('timeGrain')]",
            "amount": "[parameters('amount')]",
            "category": "Cost",
            "notifications": {
                "NotificationForExceededBudget1": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "operator": "GreaterThan",
                    "threshold": "[parameters('firstThreshold')]",
                    "contactEmails": "[parameters('contactEmails')]",
                    "contactGroups": "[parameters('contactGroups')]"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

And here is the combined code that I have come up with - **Not Getting the option to select Resource Group**

**Problem** - While deploying the combined template I am **not** getting the option to select "Resource Group" I need to have "Resource Group" to create Action Group but not for Budget Alert.
How can I combine the two templates?

**Not able to make it work**

```
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "microsoft.insights/actionGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
        "name": "OG",
        "location": "Global",
        "properties": {
            "groupShortName": "OG",
            "enabled": true,
            "emailReceivers": [
                {
                    "name": "[concat('Test','OG')]",
                    "emailAddress": "someemailID@xxx.com",
                    "useCommonAlertSchema": true
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Consumption/budgets",
        "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
        "name": "[parameters('budgetName')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/actionGroups','OG')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "timePeriod": {
                "startDate": "[parameters('startDate')]",
                "endDate": "[parameters('endDate')]"
            },
            "timeGrain": "[parameters('timeGrain')]",
            "amount": "[parameters('amount')]",
            "category": "Cost",
            "notifications": {
                "NotificationForExceededBudget1": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "operator": "GreaterThan",
                    "threshold": "[parameters('firstThreshold')]",
                    "contactEmails": "[parameters('contactEmails')]",
                    "contactGroups": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/actionGroups','OG')]"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please nested the budget in a nest template and target it to subscription level (or management group level)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-to-resource-group?tabs=azure-cli

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [
        {
          your action group resource
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "name": "nestedDeployment",
            "location": "centralus",
            "subscriptionId": "0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    your budget resource goes here
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```